# What is wrong with the conditions, I can't validate user input in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to ensure the user insert the right string but so far it seems the solution just loves eluding me. Its a mini paper, scissors, rock game. If the user inputs some other string except the allowedString, he should be asked to continue then the prompt dialogue will then come up. Here is the code.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} 
else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1,choice2)
{

    ch(choice1);
    if (choice1 === choice2){
        return"The result is a tie!";
    }
    else if (choice1==="rock"){
        if (choice2==="scissors"){
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else {
            return"paper wins";
        }
    }
    else if(choice1==="paper"){
        if(choice2==="rock"){
            return"paper wins";
        }
        else {
            return"scissors wins";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1==="scissors"){
        if(choice2 ==="rock"){
            return"rock wins";
        }
        else{
            return"scissors wins";
        }
     }
 }


 var ch = function(user)
 {
     allowedString = ["paper", "scissors", "rock"];
     if (!Boolean(user in allowedString)){
         if (confirm("Your choice is invalid, Do you want to try again?")) {
             userChoice = prompt("Choose rock, paper or scissors?");
             compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
         } 
         else{
             console.log("Thanks for playing");
         }
     }
     else return;
 }
 compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Error messages? Wrong output? Computer exploding?

Comment: I am not sure if you can put in a Math.random variable a string.. Why not try to change the name of the string you want to print.

Comment: I'm trying to debug and it seems that the browser doesn't recognize `Console.log()`

Comment: Inappropriate transfer of dollars into my account from Swiss banks. Actually its wrong output Juhana. @Leonidas I believe variables in Javascript can hold any kind of data, Numbers inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

You had a little imprecision in `ch` validation function. It always returned error.

```
if (allowedString.indexOf(user) > -1)
{
   console.log('ok');
   return;
}
```

I think now it works as expected. Let me know if it's ok.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t5gf0tt7/)

Comment: Thanks Giorgio, I though using 'in' keyword should return a string if there is user in allowedString.

Comment: I discovered another problem and I have fixed it though, What do you think about the call stack after I called ch() in the compare function, seems like the call stack was on line one where I called ch() but in ch(), I returned it back to the beginning of compare(). is that possible?

Comment: You're right, if user first inputs a wrong answer and then correct, a callback to compare function remains in stack (see this fiddle for logs: http://jsfiddle.net/t5gf0tt7/4/). If you want, I can redesign the code to fix it. Or let me know if you've already solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

just for fun i wrote my version:

```
var rules = {
    rock: {beat: ['scissors'], loses: ['paper']},
    scissors: {beat: ['paper'], loses: ['rock']},
    paper: {beat: ['rock'], loses: ['scissors']}
}

var getUserChoice = function(text){
    var userChoice = prompt(text);
    if(userChoice in rules)
        return userChoice;
    return getUserChoice("Wrong choice, try again! Choose rock, paper or scissors");
};

var getComputerChoice = function(){
    return Object.keys(rules)[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
}

var getWinner = function(userChoice, computerChoice){
    if(rules[userChoice].beat.indexOf(computerChoice) !== -1)
        return 'user';
    else if(rules[userChoice].loses.indexOf(computerChoice) !== -1)
        return 'computer';
    return 'dead heat';
}

var userChoice = getUserChoice("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

var computerChoice = getComputerChoice();

var winner = getWinner(userChoice, computerChoice);

console.log('userChoice=', userChoice, ', computerChoice=', computerChoice, ', winner=', winner);
```

Comment: @user3311392 no, to get interesting feedback or to help you.

Comment: Thanks I caught a few lessons from your upgraded code. I discovered another problem and I have fixed it though, What do you think about the call stack after I called ch() in the compare function, seems like the call stack was on line one where I called ch() but in ch(), I returned it back to the beginning of compare(). is that possible?